# Java FileNotFoundException in jar file

Tags: java, spring, filenotfoundexception

I’m working on a background Spring service that runs from the command line using a nohup command.

I’m hitting the following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [templates/] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/Users/gestes/Documents/workspace/bge/bge-proj/myProcess/target/myProcess-0.2.2.jar!/templates/
```

The jar file is being created and does exist at:

```
/Users/gestes/Documents/workspace/bge/bge-proj/myProcess/target/myProcess-0.2.2.jar
```

When I extract the jar file contents, there is a /templates/ directory.

Looking at the exception, there is an “ ! “ after the jar file name, and I thought that tells what it can’t find, but clearly, it is there.

What am I missing?

Comment: Check if template folder is added on classpath of the jar being executed

Comment: `jar:file:/` should mention a file name relative to jar root. however your file name is an absolute path

Comment: The ! character is used to denote the beginning of the file path inside the jar. It is not a literal ! character being interpreted. Check your path where you are referencing the /template directory. Can you added this to your question?

Comment: what do you want to achieve? Do you want to know which files are located in /templates folder?

Answer (score 0):

If in your code you are trying to access the folder using a java `File`, you cannot do that. You need to use an `inputStream`

This is because things inside a Jar are not actually files on the disk. They are compiled inside of a jar. Yes it may be there when you extract the jar, but it's not actually a normal disk file when the jar is bundled

Comment: This is an existing project that runs as a background service that another project must interact with. It runs in the production env, etc... just have stood it up in the local env. The error happens on start-up...but have not seen where specifically it's being called from, stacktrace only lists Spring system files, nothing in the local source. I do see there is no application.properties file in the source...wondering if there is something  that should be there that could help address this.